# sqlalchemy/sql : cross model relationships, getting info from 'cousin' models

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy, datamodel

I have something I need from my data model but I am not sure what I need to be doing yet. I need some input to help me think this through.

First a general case. I have four models A, B, C, D. There is a one to many relationship for A to the rest(A can have any number of B, C, D). B, C, D have a one to many for each succeeding (B can have any number of C, etc.). This allows construction of various hierarchies, e. g. an A instance can have any number of B each with any number of C each with any number of D or an A instance could be just constructed of any number of D elements and no intervening B or C.

Using concrete terms I have Surveys that can have sections, fields, and elements. A survey might be constructed of sections with their own fields each field having a number of elements or simply a survey with a bunch of elements or a survey with fields of elements.

So, my primary question is about how to a list D for A when there is any number of intervening B or C. How do access through intervening models? I need to get the D elements even if the relationship is not direct. A.Bs.Cs.Ds isn't a valid thing in sqlalchemy by default(that I could determine) so I need to set 'something' up to do this, but I do not know what this 'something' is at this point.

edit:

I can do a list comprehension

```
[x.Ds for x in A.Cs]
```

which works as a start, but is case by case. I'd like to set it up to return Ds on A no matter the intervening relationship.

And I built a method into each model that I could pass up the D elements to the A when needed, so I've solved it for now but isn't the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of obtaining Ds objects through python associations ask SQLAlchemy to query the database for those objects.

If you have 3 foreign keys in the D model (to C, B and A) --that's what I infer from your post--, then you can obtain the D objects related to an A just using joins:

**Ds of a survey with sections, fields and elements**:

```
ds1 = session.query(D).join(C, D.c_id == C.id).join(B, C.b_id == B.id).join(A, B.a_id == A.id).filter(A.id = some_a_id).all()
```

**Ds of a survey with fields and elements**:

```
ds2 = session.query(D).join(C, D.c_id == C.id).join(A, C.a_id == A.id).filter(A.id = some_a_id).all()
```

**Ds of a survey with just elements**:

```
ds3 = session.query(D).join(A).filter(A.id = some_a_id).all()
```

In these queries, `a_id`, `b_id` and `c_id` are the names of the foreign keys that chain the models together. And `some_a_id` is just the id of the survey you're interested in.

If you want to know *all* Ds of A independently of whether there are intervening models or not, you can just append the three lists together:

**All Ds**

```
ds = ds1 + ds2 + ds3
```